# Use Power Query result as URL for follow-up query?

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I am working with an API that gives a URI as a value that I'd like to be the source for other queries (for each result).  Imagine an initial Web query returns a value like this (imagine something small but meaningful, like 100 results):

https://.../users

```json
{ "users": [
    { "name": "foo",
      "email": "foo@localhost",
      "uri": "https://example.com/user/admin-foo"
    },
    { "name": "bar",
      "email": "bar@localhost",
      "uri": "https://example.com/user/anon-bar"
    },
  ]
}
```

Power Query result:

| name | email | uri |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | foo@localhost | https://example.com/user/admin-foo |
| bar | bar@localhost | https://example.com/user/anon-bar |

What I'd like to do is to iterate over each row and use the URL to grab more details (e.g., issue a query for `https://example.com/user/admin-foo` and `https://exmaple.com/user/anon-bar`) to join on the initial query.

### Example

https://.../user/admin-foo

```json
{ "foo": {
    "name": "foo",
    "is_admin": true,
    "is_local": false,
    "ip_address": "192.168.1.100/32"
  }
}
```

https://.../user/anon-bar

```json
{ "bar": {
    "name": "bar",
    "is_admin": false,
    "is_local": false,
    "ip_address": "192.168.1.101/32"
  }
}
```

| name | email | uri | Ext.is_active | Ext.is_local |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | foo@localhost | https://example.com/user/admin-foo | true | false |
| bar | bar@localhost | https://example.com/user/anon-bar | false | false |

Comment: I also don't know if this is possible, but one thought I had was to create a new connection to "https://example.com/user/" with a parameter, which was a slice of the `uri` value.

Comment: You can use either the `List.Generate` or `List.Accumulate` function to start with your list of uri's, and create the custom api calls

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks for your insights! These seem promising.  I am just now looking into them to see if they can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simplified, something like:

```
   Calls = List.Accumulate(#"Your Sample Table"[uri],{}, (state, current)=> state & {Web.Contents(current)})
```

will return a list of the Web Contents, probably as binary, for each of the uri's in your `uri` column.

For your particular uri's the return for each, when decoded, is an error message:

```
DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from 'https://example.com/user/admin-foo' (404): Not Found
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Web
    DataSourcePath=https://example.com/user/admin-foo
    Url=https://example.com/user/admin-foo
```

```
DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from 'https://example.com/user/anon-bar' (404): Not Found
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Web
    DataSourcePath=https://example.com/user/anon-bar
    Url=https://example.com/user/anon-bar
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. They'll return 404 because the example.com is a non-functional example. It would be nicer if my question used a publicly accessible and evergreen API to demonstrate.  I'm sure something has to exist to build my requirements, I just don't know offhand and will have to look into it.

Comment: @Mike Yes, that's expected. But you should be able to adapt easily to your own real data.

Comment: This worked beautifully. I also tried to follow https://radacad.com/list-accumulate-hidden-gem-of-power-query-list-functions-in-power-bi and given my limited experience with Power Query or Power Query M, I would have made it to the lamda and not known how to proceed.  I still don't know what `state` represents there and I wouldn't have known to use `Web.contents`, but this is a great lead in for me to do the work and learn more. Thank you again!

Comment: FYI, assuming you are looking at the MS Help for `List.Accumulate`, `state` represents the current status of `seed`, which is initially set to an empty list; and current will be the element in the `List` (first argument), which is being passed to the function.